# Blazor Server App - Manual Authentication Login with CookieAuthenticationDefault?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In ASP.NET Core I used authentication like this:

Startup:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOut";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(43200); // 1 month
        });
```

Controller  :

```
 var claims = new List<Claim>()
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user.UserId.ToString()),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.Mobile.ToString()),
                    };
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true

                    };
```

Can I use this method in blazor?

How can I do it ?

Comment: You can refer this blog to create a Server-side Blazor application with Cookie Authentication: [A Demonstration of Simple Server-side Blazor Cookie Authentication](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/36).

Comment: thanks @Michael Rovinsky

This is so complicated I'm looking for an easier way